# C++ Libraries on iPhone/Android: Generation of Wrapper classes

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, mobile, wrapper

I have the following question:

Let's assume I have many different C++ libraries(algorithms), which are written in the same style . (They need some inputs and give back some outputs).

I've done some research and wanted to ask if its possible to auto-generate Wrapper classes (by using an algorithm which are given the input and the outputs of the c++ algorithm), which can be easily used in Objective-C/Java (iOS/Android)  then . 
The app-programming part isn't really time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html). This generates bindings for other languages from a C based API. [Objective-C](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.1/HTML/SWIG.html#n7) support is in there as is [Java](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java).

I'm not sure what happened to objective-C support in the later versions, but its in v1.1 and you can [see the branch](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=1645&id=276794) where it was added.